# Egress routing from specific POD in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks

I have multiples PODs(pod1, pod2 and pod3) in my kubernetes  which is configured in private subnet using a NAT gateway. All good and I have access to internet.

I would like to connect pod3 to an external endpoint (outside AWS) that performs access restriction via IP whitelisting and allows traffic from pod3, but deny the access from pod1 and pod2.

As 3 pods share the same NAT gateway IP I don't know what would be the best approach for this.

Is it possible to assign multiples NAT gateways to kubernetes and assign a specific one to pod3? Or is there a good way to route the traffic from pod3 trough a different NAT gateway?

I've read about Network Policies to customise network traffic but not sure if this allow me to assign different NATs

One approach would be creating an EC2 instance with some proxy from which I route the traffic.